# Prolog - writing a predicate that calculates the sum of two atomic statements

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have:

```
person(bob,50) . 
person(joe,60) .
```

And I want to write a predicate called 'totalAge(A)' that calculates the total value A of both atomic statements?

How would I go on doing this?

Comment: Do you mean somthing like `totalAge(ListOfPerson, TotalAge)` ?

Comment: ?- aggregate(sum(A), P^person(P,A), S).

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin the value A is the age determined. Just totalAge(A)

Answer (score 1):

You can collect all ages with `findall/3` and then sum them up with `sumlist/2`:

```
totalAge(A):-
  findall(Age, person(_, Age), Ages),
  sumlist(Ages, A).
```

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without using built in names like findAll and sumlist?

Comment: Yes, `sumlist/2` can be implemented easily. OTOT `findall/3` would require to do some hacks, e.g. backtrack all solutions for` person/2` using assert/retract to collect all the results.